# Simulate Ctrl-C to python script

Tags: python, unix, subprocess, signals

I have a python script which waits for some jobs and executes them in threads (using `subprocess.Popen` with `shell=True`). When I run a script in a shell and try to terminate it with `Ctrl-C` it closes down normally and cleanly.

The problem is I want to run this script as a daemon and then terminate it using some kind of unix signal. `INT` signal should be the same as `Ctrl-C` but it doesn't work in the same way. It leaves child processes of `subproces.popen` running.

I also tried raising `KeyboardInterupt` in main thread when I receive the signal, but that also fails to close the script and kill all children processes.

Any suggestions how to emulate `Ctrl-C`?

Example of call to `subprocess.popen`:

```
shell_cmd = "bwa aln -t 8 file1.fasta file1.fastq.gz > file1.sam.sai"
process = subprocess.Popen(shell_cmd,
                           shell=True,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: How did you send it the INT signal? `kill -s SIGINT pid` from the shell?

Comment: Yes, that was how I sent the signal. The outcome was different compared to using Ctrl-C

Answer (score 6):

Raising `KeyboardInterrupt` in the main process raises `KeyboardInterrupt` in the main process. You have to send the signal to the subprocesses.

Have you tried [`Popen.send_signal`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.send_signal)?

Or, even more straightforwardly, [`Popen.terminate`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate)?

Comment: When I run popen(comamand, shell=True) it first lauches shell process and it's child running a command. When I do .terminate() the child process keeps running.

Comment: @Rok, is it necessary to use `shell=True`? Either way, post the `Popen` call you're using.

Comment: It would be beneficial to use shell=True, since I don't want to handle standard output inside my script.

Answer (score 1):

[Ctrl-C sends SIGINT to the entire process group, not just one process](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Concepts-of-Job-Control.html).  Use `os.killpg()` or a negative process id with `kill` to send SIGINT to a process group.

Comment: This is the trick. Sending SIGINT to a single pid will only affect the specified process. Using "kill -<pg>" causes all of the descendants of the process to receive the signal, so long as they haven't changed their process group id (through setpgrp, for example). The parent processes in the same group will also receive SIGINT, but they should be ignoring it.